# Is it possible to jump to the image with href while not using captions?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, anchor, href

I am using various figures throughout my documents without captions. In order to reference them I use the command `\refstepcounter{figure}` before labelling them with `\label{fig:label}`. However, when I do this so and click on the figure reference Latex goes below the figure as if there was a caption. However, there is no caption and the command **\capstart** from the **hypcap** package does not work either. What can I do to work around this problem?

The MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I write in UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 256 glyphs are sufficient for our purposes
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption} % Provides subfigures with captions and lists them in ToC
\usepackage{hyperref} % Options configured later
\usepackage{hypcap} % For anchorage
\usepackage{float} % For additional position specifiers etc.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[6-7]
    Please see \ref{fig:try}.
    \lipsum[8-10]
    \begin{figure}[H]\capstart
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{try}
        \refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:try}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a base template that replicates this issue of yours?

Comment: @Werner I provided a MWE to illustrate the issue. It generates two pages of output.

Comment: @Vesnog your code might be much, but your Minimal Working Example doesn't seem very *minimal*.

Comment: @Skillmon I shortened my MWE.

Comment: @Vesnog: Why not use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` since there's no caption or numbering of the floats? Here's [an example](https://pastebin.com/SBdHZVV1).

Comment: @Werner Actually it seems that I have found a simpler solution. Moving the line `\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:try}` before the `\includegraphics` command seems to do the trick. By the way disabling **caption** and **subcaption** packages then using `\capstart` also seems to work. I do not know the reasons behind though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you load the `hypcap` package, the hyperref-caption feature of the `caption` package will be switched off since in this case the `caption` package assumes that you would like to use the features/commands of the `hypcap` package rather than using the hyperref-caption feature of the `caption` package.

Now to a possible solution: Similar to the `\phantom...` commands offered by the `hyperref` package the `caption` package offers `\phantomcaption`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I write in UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 256 glyphs are sufficient for our purposes
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption} % Provides subfigures with captions and lists them in ToC
\usepackage{hyperref} % Options configured later
\usepackage{float} % For additional position specifiers etc.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[6-7]
    Please see \ref{fig:try}.
    \lipsum[8-10]
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{try}
        \phantomcaption \label{fig:try}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`\phantomcaption` increases the `figure` counter (but only if `\ContinuedFloat` isn't used), takes care of the hyper-link and hyper-target, and so on, but does not typeset a caption itself.

As an alternative one could also use `\captionlistentry` which does the same as `\phantomcaption` but places an entry into the List of Figures:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I write in UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 256 glyphs are sufficient for our purposes
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption} % Provides subfigures with captions and lists them in ToC
\usepackage{hyperref} % Options configured later
\usepackage{float} % For additional position specifiers etc.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[6-7]
    Please see \ref{fig:try}.
    \lipsum[8-10]
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{try}
        \captionlistentry{Whatever} \label{fig:try}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I must confess that I'm not sure how these solutions behave if the `hypcap` package will be loaded additionally, so I recommend dropping it if you would like to use these features offered by the `caption` package.

However, both solution increment the `figure` counter and `\ref` will give you a reference to the `figure` counter. If this is not what you want, I recommend using `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` instead, just as Werner has suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it seems to leave a little bit of empty space just after the float but does what I intend to do. But moving it before the `\includegraphics` command resolved this issue. What does \phantomcaption to that \refstepcounter{figure} does not?

Comment: @Vesnog It connects the reference with the hyperref anchor the `caption` package has placed at the beginning of the `figure`. (Regarding the extra space: This should not happen, I will take a look at it...)